# Difference between new TcpClient(MachineName, port) and new TcpClient(new IPEndpoint(..., Port))

Tags: vb.net, sockets, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

Hej Hej,

I have a .Net program that has to run on a cluster of server 2008. 
To find out the right IP I resolve the dns by

```
GetHostEntry(VarDefinedInfConfig).AddressList(0)
```

but when I am converting my old code (this code picks the wrong IP) `dns.GetHostName().AddressList(0) =>` this returns a virtual IP and not the right one.

So I changed my `TcpListener` to **(dns is parameter from config)**

```
Dim listener As TcpListener = New TcpListener(New IPEndPoint(Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(dns).AddressList(0), 8001))
listener.Start()
```

In the **old way** a tcpclient was defined by this code

```
  Dim client As TcpClient = New TcpClient(Environment.MachineName, 8001)
  Console.WriteLine("Done...")
  client.Close()
```

This also connects to the wrong IP so I found the overload of `TcpClient` and used that one

**New way:**

```
 Dim client2 As TcpClient = New TcpClient(New IPEndPoint(Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(dns).AddressList(0), 8001))
    Console.WriteLine("Done")
    client2.Close()
```

But when I use the second one I got the exception "Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address / port) is normally permitted.

Weird thing is if I get the IP from the MachineName is exactly the same as the ip retreived from dns with parameter.

Does anybody know the cause of this exception? Normally they should have the same result.

Greetz,

Jonathan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible that you overlooked the main difference between the 2 mentioned TcpClient constructors ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx))?:

> TcpClient(String, Int32) .. *connects to the **specified port** on the **specified host***.
>
> TcpClient(IPEndPoint) .. *binds it to the specified **local** endpoint*.

So effectively, with the first constructor a socket is opened on an available, "OS-assigned" local port and then connected to the server, whose address or DNS-name and port are passed in as arguments;  after that you're ready to send or receive data.

With the second constructor a socket is just opened on a certain local port (which is identified in the endpoint argument), but that's all - no connection to any [remote, or even local] server is made, because no server info is known yet;  [you'd need to call one of Connect(.) methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bsb3c8f.aspx) before making any comm operations (similar to the workaround you found).

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Some people have a different, confusing error message, e.g. [TcpClient Exception: "The requested address is not valid in its context" - C# / C Sharp](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/233487-tcpclient-exception-requested-address-not-valid-its-context). In `TcpClient` class, Having two constructors that take similar-looking arguments with actually very different semantic is error-prone. If this design is actually the best compromise, MS should have included a hint in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you specify the correct IP in the application config?

> Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address / port) is normally permitted

Means that someone (your or another application) is already listening on that ip/port.

Comment: Hej, Thanks for the answer. I can't beceause an IP can change (DHCP) and our program can run under pc's that get there IPAddress from DHCP. 
I used netstat -a to confirm this and no one is using this port / IPAddress.
Question is why does it work when using the machinename and port (It has the same IP). So behind the scene it should result in same IP and port I give in the IPEndpoint. Greetz

Comment: Right now I use an work arround. 
I create an TcpClient() with an empty constuctor and then I use the Connect(IPendpoint) and this works.

Answer (score 0):

Right now I use an work arround. I create an TcpClient() with an empty constuctor and then I use the Connect(IPendpoint) and this works.